Prompt size exceeds maximum context window when chain run
This is my code to setup a retrieval chain:
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain_community.llms import GPT4All
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain import PromptTemplate

local_path = (
   "/home/user/coding/facts/models/llama-2-7b-chat.Q5_K_M.gguf"  
)

callbacks = [StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]

llm = GPT4All(
    model=local_path, 
    callbacks=callbacks, 
    verbose=True,
    temp=0,
    streaming=True)

prompt_template = """
You are a chatbot which retrieves data from a vector database.
Your task is to answer user questions by only using the data provided by the retriever.
If the retriever does not find any source documents say: "I don't know the answer".

    -----------
    Context: {context}
    -----------
    Question: {question}
"""

qa_prompt=PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=['context', 'question'],max_length = 2048)

print("loading embeddings model")
model_name = "sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2"
model_kwargs = {'device': 'cpu'}
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': False}
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name=model_name,
    model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
    encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs
)
db = Chroma(
    persist_directory="emb",
    embedding_function=embeddings
)
retriever = db.as_retriever()

chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    retriever=retriever,
    chain_type="stuff",
    chain_type_kwargs={'prompt': qa_prompt}
)

print(len(qa_prompt.template))

result = chain.run("When was Mark Twain born?")

print(result)

When printing the template length right before running chain.run it counts 321characters which are round about 80 tokens plus 10 tokens for the mentioned question. But why am I getting an error telling me that I exceed the context window size of about 2048? Ca I see what is added to the context variable? When I use the standard chain prompt template of the chain (not overriding it with chain_type_kwargs) it results in the same error. Even passing the max_length parameter does not help.

